# How to display all row data after ordering is done using union with single column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

this is probably simple but my attempts are failing one after the other.

I have created a union which uses multiple tables to sort data according to the 'position' column.

here is my code that is working:

```
  SELECT thickness, colto_section, Position
FROM (

SELECT thickness, colto_section,base_layers.position AS Position
FROM base_layers
WHERE base_layers.section_id =1
UNION 
SELECT thickness, colto_section,selects.position
FROM selects
WHERE selects.section_id =1
UNION 
SELECT thickness, colto_section,subbases.position
FROM subbases
WHERE subbases.section_id =1
)x
ORDER BY Position ASC
```

now my issue is, as I run this query it only displays the column position in the end with no data on the row. I would like It to display the full row data in the end after the ordering is done. Hope this is possible.. it will save my ass. Thanks

edit: the output in MySQL:

```
Position
1
2
3
```

I would like it to output:

```
name  lastname  id  position  
bob   hendric   3      1
den   dyno      5      2
ben   brik      3      3
```

hope that helps for something

Edit:

THANK YOU!! all is working 100%

Comment: could you give an image or demo of what is actually happening
?

Comment: @RohitTiwari I gave a small example. the complicated part is that each of those rows are from a different table. although luckily the data is similar.

Comment: name and lastname is there in all the 3 tables?

Comment: Of course it will display only Position column because it's the only item in SELECT clause. You should INNER JOIN your name and last name from whatever tables before ORDER BY clause and add these fields to SELECT clause.

Comment: name and lastname is in all 3, I will go research INNER JOIN quick :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT name,lastname,id,Position
FROM (

SELECT name,lastname,id,base_layers.position AS Position
FROM base_layers
WHERE base_layers.section_id =1
UNION 
SELECT name,lastname,id,selects.position
FROM selects
WHERE selects.section_id =1
UNION 
SELECT name,lastname,id,subbases.position
FROM subbases
WHERE subbases.section_id =1
)x
ORDER BY Position ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,lastname,Position,section_id  as 'id'
FROM (

SELECT name,lastname,section_id ,base_layers.position AS Position
FROM base_layers
WHERE base_layers.section_id =1
UNION 
SELECT name,lastname,section_id ,selects.position  AS Position
FROM selects
WHERE selects.section_id =1
UNION 
SELECT name,lastname,section_id ,subbases.position  AS Position
FROM subbases
WHERE subbases.section_id =1
)x
ORDER BY Position ASC
```

Provided name, lastname are there in your three tables.